# Acumatica Update Multiple Records

Tags: acumatica

I am new to Acumatica. Can someone guide me on how the below functionality can be achieved. I am trying something similar like sitemap functionality in Acumatica, where Parent node is mapped to multiple child nodes and it needs to be updated.

In Stock Items screen added a customized column to capture the hierarchical parent item. If there is any change all the Stock Items which is mapped to hierarchical parent Item should also be updated. It can be more than 1 record where it has to be updated.

Here is an example where I need to update multiple hierarchical parent item when there is change.

InventoryCD: PEN, PENCIL, PAPER

parent item: Stationery

can someone guide me on this ?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what you've achieved so far?

Comment: you could refer the customer screen, wherein it has a parent field.